# Javascript Form submit is not working , issue only in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I have form field and that form field gets submitted to the next page with the following javascript code.., the code is working fine in firefox but the form not getting submited in internet explorer.

```
function addarray(formId)
{
    var ara = tmm.length;

    //alert(ara);
    for(var sds=0; sds < tmm.length; sds++)
    {
        var sss = tmm[sds];;

        ara = ara+"*#*#*"+sss;
  //alert(ara);
        if(sss <= 0)
            {
            alert("\n\n\nYou should have atleast one submenu \n for each main menu \n\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    var ddf = document.blcname.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var i = 0;
    while(i < ddf.length)
    {
        var dddd = ddf[i].type;
        var vla = ddf[i].value;
        //alert(i+"----"+vla+"-----"+dddd);
        if(dddd=="text"){
            if(vla == "")
            {
                //alert("Please fill all the required fields....");
                return false;
            }
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
var setform = document.getElementById('arav');
setform.value = ara;
var formObj = document.getElementById(formId);
formObj.action = "get-code.php";
formObj.submit();            

    //document.blcname.submit();


 }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @user384210: you should try to "alert", at least to see if the function get called anytime.

Comment: P/s: you should accept some previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try alternate ways of getting to this form. Give the form HTML `id` and a `name` attribute

Also watch out if you're using frames and the form is inside of a frame.

eg.

```
document.forms[0].submit() //if its the first form in the document
document.forms[1].submit() //if its the second form in the document
document.formName.submit() //using the name attribute.
```

Comment: i have tried by using document.forms[0].submit(), coze its the first form in the document still the problem not got solved. The function is getting called, i have checked.

thanks in advance